# How to expand all or collapse all in expansionPanelList - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create an expansionPanelList in flutter which has a common button to expand All or collapse All panel at the same time.

```
class Item {
  Item({
    this.expandedValue,
    this.headerValue,
    this.isExpanded = false,
  });

  String expandedValue;
  String headerValue;
  bool isExpanded;
}

List<Item> generateItems(int numberOfItems) {
  return List.generate(numberOfItems, (int index) {
    return Item(
      headerValue: 'Panel $index',
      expandedValue: 'This is item number $index',
    );
  });
}

// ...

List<Item> _data = generateItems(8);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      child: _buildPanel(),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _buildPanel() {
  return ExpansionPanelList(
    expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
      setState(() {
        _data[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
      });
    },
    children: _data.map<ExpansionPanel>((Item item) {
      return ExpansionPanel(
        headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(item.headerValue),
          );
        },
        body: ListTile(
          title: Text(item.expandedValue),
          subtitle: Text('To delete this panel, tap the trash can icon'),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.delete),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _data.removeWhere((currentItem) => item == currentItem);
            });
          }
        ),
        isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
      );
    }).toList(),
  );
}
```

I'm trying to figure this out for a week. Please let me know what are the changes to be made. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by setting all the value of `isExpanded` to either `true` or `false` to expandAll or collapseAll respectively.

Example:

Implement a method to set all the values.

```
void _setAll(bool isExpanded) {
    for (final data in _data) {
      data.isExpanded = isExpanded ?? false;
    }
    setState(() {});
}
```

To expand on a button click,  just call

```
_setAll(true);
```

To collapse

```
_setAll(false);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to leave one open but close all others and this is what I came up with. For all who may want the same:

```
expansionCallback: (int index, bool expanded) {
        if (expanded == false) {
          for (final subop in state.options) {
            if (state.options[index] == subop) {
              setState(() {
                state.options[index].isExpanded = true;
              });
            }
            setState(() {
              subop.isExpanded = false;
            });
          }
        }

        setState(() {
          state.options[index].isExpanded = !expanded;
        });
      },
```

Comment: ExpansionPanelList.radio seems a better solution

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
    if (isExpanded == false) {
      for (final item in _books) {
        if (_books[index] != item) {
          setState(() {
            item.isExpanded = true;
          });
        }
        setState(() {
          item.isExpanded = false;
        });
      }
    }

    setState(() {
      _books[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
    });
  },
```